# Pylons app deployment with privately developed dependencies

Tags: python, deployment, setuptools, distutils

In my organization, we have a couple of internally developed Python packages. For sake of example, let's call them **Foo** and **Bar**. Both are developed in separate Git repositories. **Foo** is a Pylons application that uses certain library functions from **Bar**. Neither is publicly distributed.

When we deploy **Foo**, we typically export the latest revision from source control and run `setup.py develop` within our virtualenv. This works okay.

The problem is that we'll need some way of distributing **Bar** for every environment where we deploy **Foo**. We obviously can't put 'Bar' in setup.py's install_requires (as easy_install won't find be able to find it on any website). I can't find any way of automatically obtaining/installing *privately developed* dependencies.

Is there an easier to way to manage this? I feel like I'm missing the point of Python packaging and distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a package repository. The steps are basically:

1. Create an egg with **setup.py bdist_egg**
2. Copy the created egg from **dist** to a directory served by Apache
3. Add the url to the directory exposed by Apache to the **easy_install** command with the **-f** switch

Note that Apache is not necessarily required, but it automatically generates a directory listing that easy_install can deal with.

If you are using buildout, there are config options to do the same thing as -f and I am pretty sure there is something you can use in pip as well.

Answer (score 1):

When using setuptools, in setup.py you can specify HTTP, FTP and SVN locations where easy_install should look for packages:

http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/setuptools#dependencies-that-aren-t-in-pypi

You can either publish Bar in some "secret" location, or, I haven't tried it but maybe HTTP basic auth works:

```
setup(
    ...
    dependency_links = [
        "http://user:pass@example.com/private-repository/"
    ],
)
```

Answer (score 0):

At my work we use setuptools to create packages specific to the OS.  We happen to use RedHat so we call bdist_rpm to create rpm package.  We find that works better than eggs because we can do dependency management in the packages for both python and non-python libs.

We create the rpms on our continuous integration machine and the move them to a YUM repo where they can be pushed out via a YUM update or upgrade.